# How to get my UK criminal record from abroad?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, criminal-records

I lived in the UK for two years. To apply for a firearms certificate in my home EU country I need to show that I did not do any offences or misdemeanours during that time. How can I get such a certificate? Does one need to travel to the UK?

I am still unsure about what is the official document for a criminal record. What is the difference between Disclosure Scotland, Disclosure and Barring Service and a Police record? Which one of them is the most general and most likely be recognized as an official document of the UK government/police in other EU countries?

Answer (score 1):

You can request online www.gov.uk/request-copy-criminal-record but note that the UK handles firearms licencing by a different process, so check your home state will accept this certificate anyway

Comment: I will try the link. I do not need British FAC but my country requests criminal records from countries where I was longer than 6 months.

Comment: What is a difference between this and the Police record, that is mentioned in your link as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, you missed this note: "If you live outside the UK
You won’t be able to use the online service so you’ll need to request a paper form."

Comment: Sorry about that. The site wasn't working well on my phone. The police record includes warnings and cautions given by police which are not the same as criminal convictions received in court.